# REDMINE 2.5.1 show entire hierachy on email

Tags: ruby, redmine

My Project Structure is :

Project 1 >> Project 2 >> Project 3 >> Project 4

I have set this :

```
<%=  @issue.project.parent.name if defined?(issue.project.parent.name) %>
```

in my emails to add in the Parent project.

What is happening is:
For project 4, i only see project 3 in the H1 tag.

What i wish to achieve is it will show 
Project 1 >> Project 2 >> Project 3 .

Anyone knows hows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Adding:

```
<h3>Project Tree: <%=  "#{issue.project.parent.name} " if defined?(issue.project.parent.name) %>
 <%=  "> #{issue.project.parent.parent.name}"  if defined?(issue.project.parent.parent.name) %>
 <%=  "> #{issue.project.parent.parent.parent.name}" if defined?(issue.project.parent.parent.parent.name) %>
 <%=  "> #{issue.project.parent.parent.parent.parent.name}" if defined?(issue.project.parent.parent.parent.parent.name) %>
 <%=  "> #{issue.project.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.name}" if defined?(issue.project.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.name) %>
 <%=  "> #{issue.project.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.name}" if defined?(issue.project.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.name) %>
 <%=  "> #{issue.project.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.name}" if defined?(issue.project.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.name) %></h3>
```

This will display 
 Project Tree: Parent > Grand Parent > Ancestor > Until > Root > UpTo > 7 Times

If the hierarchy is less than 7 times, dont worry it will not return an error, it will just display until the root.

Comment: if anyone can suggest a more dynamic solution please do help out!

Comment: I think you should use recursion for this. Smth like this [example](https://gist.github.com/gotva/7f6848ec94462948b5d4) (not tested!)